# why the for loop is not playing audio files again and again?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, audio

for full code please visit **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249752/dynamically-playing-multiple-sounds-using-javascript)**

for now the problem which is coming in the code is:

```
var times_played =1,
     l=pattern_config[actions().whichPattern].WP_slotsCounter;
var p = setInterval(function(){
    var x = pattern[actions().whichPattern][times_played];
    for(var i=0; i<x.length;i++){
            var toBePlayed = x[i];
           if(toBePlayed !== undefined){    
            var url= "All Drums sounds/"+toBePlayed+".wav";
            audio.src = url;
            audio.play();
            //console.log(audio);
        }else{};
    }
    times_played++;
    console.log(l);
    if(times_played === l+1){clearInterval(p);};
}, pattern_config[actions().whichPattern].delay);
```

**Note:** its a part of a function named `_play()`

and the problem is that:

suppose i have an array like: `[['drum_snare_01'],['drum_snare_01'],['drum_snare_01']]`. So i should expect my function to play the audio file named `'drum_snare_01'` 3 times. but it is not happening it is playing only once. From debugging i get to know that this file is played after the loop is over, i.e. at the last.

### Case 2

again if i have an array like: `[[ 'kick_02','drum_snare_01'],[ 'kick_02','drum_snare_01'],[ 'kick_02','drum_snare_01'],[ 'kick_02','drum_snare_01']]` then it is going to play only `drum_snare_01` and not `kick_02` or in general it will play the file which is at the last of the array

i don't know how the solution of this problem is going to be, that's why i finally asked here.

Comment: use setInterval method..

Comment: there is a change now it is playing the file which is at the first index of the array